# Non-conformable arguments when using mapply

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a function func that looks like this:

```
func<- function(beta,X){
  res <-  t(beta) %*% t(X) %*% X %*% beta
  return(res)
}
```

where X = design matrix and I have two matrices

```
b1 <- matrix(data = c(0.8, 3.6), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
b2 <- matrix(data = c(1.56, 0.27), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

when I call the function on each matrix it works fine, and produces a result.

```
func(b2,xm)
         [,1]
[1,] 213.6931

func(b1,xm)
         [,1]
[1,] 23138.99
```

However when I add these two matrices to a list, and try calling func using mapply I get a non-conformable arguments error.

```
b3 <- list(b1,b2)
mapply(func, c, X=xm)
#Error in t(beta) %*% t(X) : non-conformable arguments
```

I cannot understand why this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `xm` in your code?

Comment: @phiver is is the design matrix X. it is a matrix with 2 cols, n rows.

Comment: You need to pass that too maybe, `mapply(func, b3, list(xm))`

Comment: @RLave ah. it's a typo. I'll edit the question, forgot to put it in the mapply

Comment: It is enough to use `sapply` here, like this `sapply(b3, func, xm)`.

Comment: @djhurio this works as well, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `xm` as `list()`

```
mapply(func, b3, list(xm))
[1] 390.5600  23.2569
```

Data:

```
xm <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2,nrow=2)
b1 <- matrix(data = c(0.8, 3.6), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
b2 <- matrix(data = c(1.56, 0.27), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
b3 <- list(b1,b2)

func<- function(beta,X){
  res <-  t(beta) %*% t(X) %*% X %*% beta
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: hmm it does seem to work, but I'm not sure why. Is it because anything you pass using mapply needs to be a list?

Comment: To `mapply` you can pass also two vectors. Probably here R had some confusion because you pass a list and a matrix, likely there was a problem with that.